# Allow local webservice to update Rails data with CanCan and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, devise, cancan

I have a local webservice running which needs to POST data to Rails in order to update and add records. How should I work this into my CanCan/Devise authentication/authorization? Is there a way to allow localhost-only access around authorization, or to create a persistent session with the other service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you wanna grant access locally,

```
# application_controller.rb
def current_ability
   @current_ability ||= Ability.new(current_user, request.local?)
end

# ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user, local)
    can(:manage, :all) if local
    ...
  end
end
```